# Forcing two generics to be the same in impl

Tags: generics, rust, traits, bounds

I have a `Hittable` trait, with a method that returns a generic implementing `Material`:

```rust
pub trait Hittable {
    fn hit<T>(&self -> Option<HitRecord<T>>
    where T: Material;
}
```

And an implementation of this trait on a `Sphere<T>`:

```rust
impl<T> Hittable for Sphere<T>
where T: Material
{
    fn hit(&self) -> Option<HitRecord<T>> {
        // snip
    }
```

I want the `T` in `HitRecords` to be the same as the `T` in `Sphere<T>`, but as of now now it will not compile because I need to annotate the `hit` method in the impl with a T as well. But if I do so, the 2 T's will not be forced to be the same. How do I enforce that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should uplift the generic parameter from the method into the trait:

```rust
pub trait Hittable<T: Material> {
    fn hit(&self) -> Option<HitRecord<T>>;
}

impl<T: Material> Hittable<T> for Sphere<T> {
    fn hit(&self) -> Option<HitRecord<T>> {
        // snip
    }
}
```

Another way is to use an associated type (it models the situation better, but as long as you only implement the trait for one generic parameter it doesn't practically matter):

```rust
pub trait Hittable {
    type T: Material;
    fn hit(&self) -> Option<HitRecord<Self::T>>;
}

impl<T: Material> Hittable for Sphere<T> {
    type T = T;
    fn hit(&self) -> Option<HitRecord<T>> {
        // snip
    }
}
```